# ASP.NET MVC Base Class Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have several `Controllers` which all inherit a `BaseController`.

I have an Admin `Area` setup where Controllers inherit the `BaseController`. Inside the `BaseController` there is a method called `public JsonResult DoSomething()`. If some of these `Controllers` have a View of which a `Url.Action` is defined, how can I reference that `DoSomething()` method in the base controller with an Area reference?

```
BaseController
FruitController : BaseController
VegetableController : BaseController
```

Index View of FruitController has a call to

```
@Url.Action("DoSomething", ???, new { area = "Admin" })
```

I dont think there is a constructor with action and just variables. Am I just stuck with defining `public JsonResult DoSomething()` in each Controller regardless of it being in the BaseController as I can't seem to call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You call `DoSomething` on the controller you're currently in.. because it inherits the `BaseController`, it too will have the `DoSomething` action. However, the view it returns must be under the correct controllers view folder.. otherwise you'll have to explicitly state where the view is..

```
@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Fruit", ...
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid. I think its too much effort creating the actual View where as if you define it from the controller itself. Another route I suppose that could be used is just defining it in the global.asax. I was hoping to not do any of these and just call into the basecontroller but that won't work it seems.

Comment: You can "call into the base controller".. that's what I'm saying. You don't have to define a DoSomething action on every controller.. by inheriting from the BaseController, they automatically have that action. Put the view under a Base folder in your views and the MVC engine will search for it.

Comment: I did what you advised as I thought it would work too. Despite making the Base folder and creating the View, it just doesn't seem to want to hit.